# Check if element has display: none AFTER all content loads

Tags: jquery, css, api

I've checked numerous SO posts but haven't found a solution.

I have a webpage that displays a search bar. Below that is a "loading properties" message. That message is in a div and while it is displayed, it has a "display: block" rule. When it disappears, it has a "display: none". What replaces that "loading properties" message is other content that is fetched from an api.

I would like to apply some jquery to the new api content.

I figured the following would work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($("element").css("display") == 'none') {
        // apply the code here
    }
})
```

However, that doesn't work. I could probably use setInterval for this, but I feel it's a sloppy solution (which I've used in the past) since the api content doesn't always load at the same exact time (depending on internet connection, etc).

**How can I run a jQuery function after the api content displays?** If there are SO posts that you can refer me to, please do. None I've come across have helped me.

The problem is that once everything on my page finishes loading, the api content is still busy "fetching" the data, and the "loading properties" message is still there. How can I apply my jQuery function once it's done fetching and the content is displayed?

Comment: You have to be able to have a reference to the ajax call that loads the extra data, and apply a callback to that.  `ready()` does not take into account ajax calls in determining that the page is ready.

Comment: Hi @Taplar, I figured out a solution that I think is more in line with what you said. Instead of using jQuery, I just filtered out the results that I did not want from the api data. A much better solution in my opinion. The reason why I asked how to run a jQuery function after api content finishes loading/displaying was because I wanted to implement a weird solution that involved grabbing a piece of the data, determining if it matched a condition, and then applying a css rule to it. It was extremely amateurish. And thank you for the point about ready(). I did not know that.

Comment: @Taplar, so I guess the answer to my question is, you can't? (if yes, then I'd like to mark your response as the answer) Even though I already found a solution to my problem, I'd love to know if there's a way.

Answer (score -1):

I know the old way :

```
let element = document.querySelector('.element');
//if it's an id your looking for you can use # sign

if(element.style.display === 'none'){
    //Do something... 
}
```